# Why this ajax post request does not work in mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have js file with ajax request

this is part of its text

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/Points/Addpoint', // также '@Url.Action("Addpoint", "PointsController")'
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify({ firstx: ev._x, firsty: ev._y, secondx: ev._x, secondy: ev._y }),
       success: function () {
                               alert();
                           }
});
```

i also have mvc controller with this method which should be called in ajax

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Addpoint(JSON po)
        {
            var pointslist = this.Getpoints();
            var obj = po;
            pointslist.Add(new Point());

        }
```

But somehow this doesnt work. idk why?it gives me 500 error and message

> There are no parameterless constructors defined for this object.

what should i do to solve this problem and send this json obj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the JSON to class and change your post

```
        public class YourClass 
        {
            public string firstx { get; set; }
            public string firsty { get; set; }
            public string secondx { get; set; }
            public string secondy { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Addpoint([FromBody] YourClass po)
        {
            var pointslist = this.Getpoints();
            var obj = po;
            pointslist.Add(new Point());
        }
    $.ajax({
           url: '/Points/Addpoint',
           type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
           data: JSON.stringify({ firstx: ev._x, firsty: ev._y, secondx:ev._x,secondy: ev._y }),
           success: function () {

                               }
        });
```